# Weird console error when vuex action return false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hy there,

I try to make a custom navigation guard with vue using vuex actions.

The code for the router guard is looking like this:

router.js

```
    {
      path: '/authusersonly',
      name: 'authusersonly',
      component: loadView('authusersonly'),
      async beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
        try {
          let authStatus = await store.dispatch('pingAuth', 'checkAuth')
          if (authStatus) next()
          else next('/login')
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          next('/')
        }
      }
    }
```

The code from store.js file is looking like this

```
actions: {
    async pingAuth ({ commit, state, getters, dispatch }, action) {
      let pingStatus = getters.pingStatus
      if (!pingStatus) {
         // here i do the user check using axios with await axios.......        
      }
      // here i return the results true or false
      return false
    }
  }
```

The code work perfect but when the pingAuth action return false i get weird console error the user is redirected correctly even when the error appear.

If the pingAuth return true no error is present in the console.
The error is different in firefox and chrome.

Firefox Error
[image: Firefox Console Error]

Chrome Error
[image: Chrome Error]

I have tried to reproduce the issue in a codesandbox but the error doesn't apper. I have also tried the code with a new clean vue project (all dependencies to latest versions) and have the same error.

Can anyone explain why i get this error ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

@vue/cli 4.0.5 on ubuntu 19

package.js

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "date-fns": "1.29.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.14.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.12.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.12.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vueth": "file:../plugin/",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

**Edit:**

I tried to isolate the problem. 
The problem came from router navigation.

I have created a repo for my problem.

```
git clone https://github.com/thenutz/vue-router-error.git

yarn install

yarn serve
```

Another interesting thing is if i'm using router-link for navigation no error is present.

I found a fix for this error.

If i use `@click="$router.push({ path: '/protected' }).catch((err) => {})"` instead of `@click="$router.push({ path: '/protected' })"` no error is present.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if it's the case. You are visiting the 'login' page and you use next('login') to the same page. So need to determine whether the same page, if so just use 'next()'.